# Create shortcut with today's date in the target

Tags: shortcuts, file-shortcut

I am working with a sequence of files which contain today's date in the title (e.g. contributions_20220909.csv). I want to create a shortcut which allows me to open today's file in read-only mode e.g.
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /r contributions_%DATE%.csv"`. [It's possible](https://superuser.com/questions/972798/environment-variable-in-lnk-shortcut) to use an environment variable in a .lnk target, but I don't know how to do this if the target also has spaces.

I would prefer not to use CMD or Powershell if possible, since the link would ideally live on a network drive and I have an irrational fear of downloading and running a Powershell script from anything that looks like the Internet.

Comment: There is actually a variable in Windows which returns the current date: %date%...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've added it to the question. One thing I missed though, do you know how to include environment variables in .lnk targets if they also contain spaces?

Comment: Yes you will have to use quotes...

Comment: I did try using quotes. `$Shortcut.TargetPath = "'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE' /r faculty_contributions_%DATE%.csv"`. I got the error, "Value does not fall within the expected range". Using different arrangements of quotes didn't help.

Comment: You also have to format the %date% variable since slashes are not allowed for filenames something like: %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2% to get 20220908 instead of 08/09/2022...

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do will need a batch script of some kind, but administrative rights won't be needed. First thing you must do on any computer that uses the script is to tell windows not to use / as a separator. / cannot be used in filenames. Go to control panel, region, formats, additional settings, then type in your new date format. Using year to start as it lists better.

[image: control panel date seperator]

Then when you create a file/folder with the date, `mkdir %date%` will create a folder with the date in a usable format.

[image: cmd output]